# Visual Studio Recovery

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express, recovery

My computer randomly shut down on me and I wound up losing the project I was working on. I am using Visual C# Express and no sort of auto recovery or anything kicked in. Does C# Express have an auto recovery, or is that only Visual Studio?

Comment: I know Visual Studio has it, but no idea about Visual C# Express. Either way, though, the feature hasn't helped me in the full suite either... if you lose anything, AutoRecover doesn't really usually help. So I suggest you just get used to pressing the Ctrl-Shift-S combination frequently, and at the right times, and just hope for the best. :)

Comment: K, well thanks. I usually just press Ctrl+s and always wondered why it didn't save anything at all (i normally start new projects). Just looked at the file menu and found out why.

Comment: Yeah, I learned it the hard way too haha. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# Express (if I remember right) has the feature exactly like it is in the normal VS suite, but it is by default disabled. if you go Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover you can turn it on.  Like it was already said though, this only works on the active file and it seems to be haphazard.  Use with caution in other words.

The best solution, post mortem, would be to increase the frequency of saving.  When I finish writing or editing a method, class, file, anything that is in a working state, I like to save it locally. I submit to source control once it is ready for that, but locally I save far too much. I also lose very little work if something goes wrong.

Comment: Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover is not there. I only have "General" "Fonts and Colors" and "Keyboard".

Comment: There isn't a "Show all Settings" button or something there, is there? IIRC, I think I saw something like that somewhere, but I could very well be wrong..

Answer (score 1):

In VS you Can go to `Tools > Options` in the menu
Then to `Environment> AutoRecover` to set AutoRecover setting.
Keep in mind that AutoRecover seems to only save the info for the page your are currently working on. So like Lambert said "press the Ctrl-Shift-S combination frequently".

**Also AutoRecover only kicks in once you have first saved your project**

Also your work should save each time you Run your app.
But the real solution here is to stop your pc from randomlly shutting down.
i suggest you head over to [superuser](https://superuser.com/) to try and fix your pc

Answer (score 0):

I use C# Express and VS 2010 and if you save your solution first, then it *seems* to auto-recover. So save the solution as soon as possible.

Also, if you're going to keep the code for more than 10 minutes then commit it to some sort of source control: [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [cvs](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/), [git](http://git-scm.com/), [darcs](http://darcs.net/), etc.